# How to automatic start recording and duplicating the sound wave in Audacity

Tags: audio-recording, audacity

I am trying to record a sound wave through mic in audacity and generating its inverse simultaneously. and want to play them simultaneously, but have been unable to do that till now. Is there any way to do this?

Answer (score 0):

I'm not 100% sure, but think you have to link the 2 channels/streams together after it's been recorded into Audacity. If i remember correctly you can do it when holding down control and just clicking the name at the start of the stream. Fairly sure that works with several recordings.

If it worked on a previous version then install it :)